# How to solve SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'http_proxy' (OS Error: No such host is known. , errno = 11001)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http

Iam trying to create and run a flutter desktop application in visual studio 2019, i already select a device that i created in android studio and i still get an error

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50673/YdQ32hZTqMc=/ws